# How to call magic method of instance variable?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I assigned an object to instance variable. This object has magic method __invoke. This does not work, because class has no method dom().

```
$this->dom = str_get_dom($template_data);
$this->dom('some arg');
```

Outside class, this code works:

```
$dom = str_get_dom($template_data);
$dom('some arg');
```

How can I make it work into my class? This example is about php lib called ganon.

Comment: Never tried, but `$this->__invoke('some arg')` seems likely.

Comment: I found that this works too: $dom = $this->dom;
    $this->year_node = $dom('#year')[0]->detach(); But I think this is perversion...

Comment: As long as $dom is actually an object with a public __invoke method, you can trigger the invoke any time you do `$dom()`, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke That's simply how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that PHP makes a difference between *object methods* and *object properties.* The syntax `$foo->bar()` requires the class of `$foo` to have a `public function bar` defined. It will *not* look for a property `bar` and then try to invoke its value as a callable.

You will have to use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) to explicitly call a value as a function.